# Laravel Jobs to get data from API

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I have this database table which is going to be updated continuously.

```
game_id | end_time
```

---

Now how can I create a job that will run on this `end_time`, a job will get some data from third-Party API which is gonna be depended from this `game_id`.

> Note: game_id and end_time changes from every record.

I have looked-up on task scheduler but I cant find information I think that is only for a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use laravel scheduler for this task. You can look at the time variable inside the console command class.
For example put in your kernel class:

```
$schedule->command('ApiConnection:get')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

And in your ApiConnection class (handle() function) you can get your DB records:

```
Model::whereDate('end_time', '>=', Carbon::today())->get(); //format of Carbon function should be equal to your end_time column format, I mean I don't know if you use just date or date with time, etc
```

And now you should be able to use game_id data by time.

I also suggest to add status column in your DB table, so you can control what records is already handled, like this:

```
$models = Model::whereDate('end_time', '>=', Carbon::today())->where('status', 'awaiting')->get();
foreach ($models as $model) {
   $model->status = 'in progress';
   ...your api work here...
   $model->status = 'completed';
}
```